# Ошибка в модели Django: on_delete must be callable

Tags: python, django, консоль, model

Столкнулся с ошибкой при запуске Джанго: "on_delete must be callable".
Подскажите, почему `on_delete` должен быть `callable`, как это здесь работает?

Файл models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
import misaka

from groups.models import Group

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts',null=True, blank=True, on_delete='models.DO_NOTHING')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,*kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single',kwargs={'username':self.user.username, 'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user','message']
```

Traceback ошибки:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+Django_Udemy\simple_social_clone\simplesocial\posts\models.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+Django_Udemy\simple_social_clone\simplesocial\posts\models.py", line 18, in Post
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts',null=True, blank=True, on_delete='models.DO_NOTHING')
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 813, in __init__
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
TypeError: on_delete must be callable.
```

Comment: в модели должно быть просто on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING без кавычек... вы сами-то читаете Traceback или сразу сюда сбрасываете? ))

Comment: Конечно же читаю) в прошлом я сам был так и понял в чем ошибка, здесь же я не совсем понимаю, почему on_delete должен быть "callable", типо как это здесь работает

Comment: Jack_oS, дайте мне пожалуйста ответ на мой вопрос, и смените пожалуйста минус, я вам все объяснил, а то меня заблочило

Comment: **в вашем вопросе нет вопроса...** есть код и трейсбек, в котором указана строка с ошибкой, как ее исправить я написал еще вчера в первом же комментарии ps где-то указано, что это мой минус? ;) pps что значит "заблочило"?

Comment: заблочило, это значит, что не могу задавать вопросы, нужно чтобы положительный вклад превысил отрицательный рейтинг предыдущих сообщений

ну я просто сформулировал свой вопрос как факт, так не только я делаю, ошибку я исправил, но я попросил объяснить, почему models.DO_NOTHING должен быть 'callable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть ошибки в строках ниже:

```
File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+Django_Udemy\simple_social_clone\simplesocial\posts\models.py", line 18, in Post
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts',null=True, blank=True, on_delete='models.DO_NOTHING')
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 813, in __init__
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
TypeError: on_delete must be callable.
```

Она буквально означает, что пераметр `on_delete` в 18-й строке, [согласно документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), должен быть вызываемым (а не строка, как вы пытаетесь передать).
Загляните в реализацию [класса ForeignKey](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py) и [функции CASCADE](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py) для большего понимания устройства Django.

Comment: если вы бы сняли минус, был бы вообще благодарен